# Sigma-algebra of two subsets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $A, B \subset X$. Define $\varepsilon:=$ {A,B} $\in$  $\mathcal{P}(X)$ .

How to find the sigma-algebra generated by $\varepsilon$?

I got $\sigma(\varepsilon)$=
{$\emptyset, X, A, A^c, B, B^c, A \cup B, A^c \cup B, A \cup B^c, A^c \cap B^c, A \cap B, A^c \cup B, A \cap B^c, A^c \cap B^c$}.

Besides, how many elements can $\sigma(\varepsilon)$ have at most? I got 14 (elements of the sigma-algebra):
$\emptyset, X, A, A^c, B, B^c, A \cup B, A^c \cup B, A \cup B^c, A^c \cap B^c, A \cap B, A^c \cup B, A \cap B^c, A^c \cap B^c.$

Also, how to choose examples of $X, A, B$ such that $\sigma(\varepsilon)$ has less elements than the maximum?

Comment: Necessarily $A$, $B^c$ are in $\sigma-$algebra, then $A^c\cap B=(A\cup B^c)^c$ is. Also $A\cap B=(A^c\cup B^c)^c$ is.

Comment: An aside: Note $\{A,B\} \subset \mathcal P(X)$, not ${}\in \mathcal P(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be subsets of $X$.

These sets induce the following "pseudo"-partition of $X$:$$\mathcal P=\{E_1\cap\cdots\cap E_n\mid E_i\in\{A_i,A_i^{\complement}\}\text{ for }i=1,\dots,n\}$$
Observe that every pair of distinct elements of $\mathcal P$ has an empty intersection and that $X$ is covered by the elements of $\mathcal P$. It is not necessarily a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) because $\mathcal P$ might contain the empty set.

Further observe that $\mathcal P$ has at most $2^n$ elements. If $\mathcal A=\sigma(\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\})$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets $A_1,\dots,A_n$ then evidently $\mathcal P\subseteq\mathcal A$.

Now define:$$\mathcal A'=\{\cup\mathcal V\mid\mathcal V\subseteq\mathcal P\}$$in word: $A$ is an element of $\mathcal A'$ if and only if it can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal P$.

Since $\mathcal P$ is finite every element of $\mathcal A'$ will be a finite union of elements of $\mathcal P$ so that from $\mathcal P\subseteq\mathcal A$ we can conclude that also $\mathcal A'\subseteq\mathcal A$.

Secondly it is easy to see that $\mathcal A'$ is closed under arbitrary unions (a union of unions is again a union).

Also it is not difficult to see that $\mathcal A'$ is closed under complements.

For that just note that $(\cup\mathcal V)^{\complement}=\cup(\mathcal P-\mathcal V)$.

This tells us that $\mathcal A'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Finally observe that $A_i\in\mathcal P$ for every $i\in\{1,\dots\}$.

As an example note that: $$A_1=\cup\{A_1\cap E_2\cap\cdots\cap E_n\mid E_i\in\{A_i,A_i^{\complement}\}\text{ for }i=2,\dots,n\}$$

These facts together tell us that $\mathcal A'=\mathcal A$.

On base of the fact that $\mathcal P$ has at most $2^n$ elements we find on base of the definition of $\mathcal A'$ that $\mathcal A=\mathcal A'$ has at most $2^{2^n}$ elements (any element of $\mathcal P$ belongs to the union or belongs not to the union).

---

Your $14$ is wrong and should be $2^{2^2}=2^4=16$.

The sets:

- $\varnothing$

(empty union)

- $A\cap B$
- $A\cap B^{\complement}$
- $A^{\complement}\cap B$
- $A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}$

(exactly $1$ element of $\mathcal P$ in the union)

- $A$
- $B$
- $A^{\complement}$
- $B^{\complement}$
- $(A\cap B)\cup(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})$
- $(A^{\complement}\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{\complement})$

(exactly $2$ elements of $\mathcal P$ in the union)

- $X-(A\cap B)=A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}$
- $X-(A\cap B^{\complement})=A^{\complement}\cup B$
- $X-(A^{\complement}\cap B)=A\cup B^{\complement}$
- $X-(A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement})=A\cup B$

(exactly $3$ elements of $\mathcal P$ in the union)

- $X$

(exactly $4$ elements of $\mathcal P$ in the union)

Answer (score 2):

If $A,B$ are "most general" (not $A \subseteq B$ or reversely, non-empty intersection and $A \cup B \neq X$) we get in the $\sigma$-algebra all sets $ A \cap B, A \setminus B, B \setminus A, X\setminus (A \cup B)$, which are 4 (non-empty, as I assumed) sets that form a disjoint partition of $X$. So if we just add all possible unions of those $4$ we are done generating the $\sigma$-algebra, because we cannot add any more by intersections (except $\emptyset$ which we already get as the empty union, i.e. the union of $0$ sets from the partition, anyway) and complements of unions are unions already (in a partition). So we get $2^4$ sets in the generated $\sigma$-algebra (or just algebra, as we're never going to get infinite unions or intersections anyway, starting from finitely many sets).

As a result I get $$\{\emptyset, A^c \cap B^c, A^c \cap B, A^c, A \cap B, (A \Delta B)^c, B, A^c \cup B, A \cap B^c, B^c, A \Delta B, A^c \cup B^c, A, B^c \cup A, A \cup B, X\}$$

Comment: So $\sigma(\varepsilon)$ has 16 elements. I found these: $\sigma(\varepsilon)$=       
{$\emptyset, X, A, A^c, B, B^c, A \cup B, A^c \cup B, A \cup B^c, A^c \cap B^c, A \cap B, A^c \cup B, A \cap B^c, A^c \cap B^c$}. Which two are missing?

Comment: @Tartulop miss $(A \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)$ already. And $A^c \cap B$. And $A \Delta B$. You mention $A^c \cup B$ twice.

Comment: @Tartulop $A^c \cap B^c$ you also mention twice. Be careful.